# how to copy all the data of a table to a new table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I m using MySQL**
i have one x table n corresponding mvc and y table n corresponding model only. when I select a destroy in x's view, it should fulfill two tasks. Firstly, destroy the id from x table and save all the data starting from id.... to y's table
Please guide me what relationship I should make and how to do it.
I tried lot of coding related to it but I m failed, reason being lack of deep knowledge of ruby on rails..
Please help

Comment: Whoever is voting this down, please at least state why. English obviously isn't his first language, and his question is a decent one. Dealing with archived data isn't always trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [acts_as_archive](https://github.com/winton/acts_as_archive). This does what I think you're asking for here.

Edit:

1. Don't use Rails 2.3.5. Upgrade to
   2.3.11 or switch to Rails 3, which you might as well do since you said
   you were just learning anyway.
2. For the gem version, just follow the
   `acts_as_archive` instructions and
   use whatever the latest version is.
3. Regarding where to put it, you
   should read up on [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/). Pay
   special attention to the section on
   that page called "Using Bundler with
   Frameworks". Reading a Rails
   tutorial wouldn't hurt either, I
   suspect.

Comment: can you please guide what vrsion gem i should install for ruby on rails 2.3.5 and where to store the file. As ruby is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to use a trigger in the database? Is the archive something for you, the developer, or is it necessary to be able to access the archived information from the application?

If you need the data from the code, then check out @jdl's posted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Id is a primary key and its maintain by the rails, so you could not delete it from a row in db. There are some workarounds to skip this but those are not good ways to do such things

solution to your problem: you can delete the complete record from table x and can add its entry to other table, also the id can not be same as deleted object so you can add a column say x_id into table to store it.

Comment: hi mr. Naren Thanks for replying.... I already have x_id... the thing is I dnt knw how to add all these data in Y table...that I was asking for, this action should happen only when I destroy the X id from x table ( FROM X VIEW )

Comment: yes, I got your point. In this case if you want to do it without using any plugin, you need to serialize x active record object and store it in a column of y.  Otherwise acts_as_archive is very helpful and I agree with jdl's response.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by fetching each item from from x table and inserted to y column. than destroy command.